# What does register state mean?

Tags: assembly

Sorry, If I am asking a too silly question! but I googled and couldn't found any answer on the same. What exactly does register state means in assembly language programming.

Comment: "state" - the current conditions of some environment. e.g. "after the riot, the stadium was in a horrible state". register state = the current values of a set of registers at some point in time.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now.

Comment: In the general context `register state` would generally mean the status and values of all the computers registers (and usually the current flags).

Answer (score 0):

[Register states:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_state_segment#Register_states)

The TSS may contain saved values of all the x86 registers. This is used for task switching. The operating system may load the TSS with the values of the registers that the new task needs and after executing a hardware task switch (such as with an IRET instruction) the x86 CPU will load the saved values from the TSS into the appropriate registers. Note that some modern operating systems such as Windows and Linux[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_state_segment#Register_states) do not use these fields in the TSS as they implement software task switching.

Answer (score 0):

May be you're referring to the status register or status word.

In many processors there are a few one-bit values that influence what the behavior should be. For example there is normally a "carry" bit, an "overflow" bit, a "zero" bit, a "negative" bit and so on. These status bit may for example change depending on the last math operation or comparison performed and can influence how conditional jumps will behave.

There could also be bits that are more "sticky", i.e. they can only change with explicit set instructions and that influence processor behavior (for example a "decimal" bit or a "interrupt enable" bit).

All these one-bit values are normally stored in a single register.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard the term "register state".  It sounds like a subset, or maybe synonym, of [Architectural state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_state).  One way of describing it is **everything that needs to be saved/restored on a context switch**.  It's the contents of the integer/general-purpose registers, the instruction pointer (next insn to execute), the flags register, the FPU registers, the vector registers, and any/all "special" registers where code can set or clear bits to modify operation of the CPU.

It does *not* include contents of the caches, or contents of main memory.

The [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) for a machine is defined in terms of what each instruction does to the architectural state.  (e.g. `add r32, r/m32` adds the src (reg or memory) to the dest register, and sets the flags according to the result.  It can also generate an exception under certain conditions.  For an example, see Intel's manuals for [x86](/questions/tagged/x86), linked from the tag wiki.

Actual implementations pipeline execution, and even run multiple instructions at once, but keep track of things in a way that gives identical results to executing every instruction in program order.  ([VLIW architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_long_instruction_word), where machine code represents bundles of instructions that execute together, are an exception to this rule.)

An [Intel SandyBridge](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/5/) uses a physical register file of 160 integer registers for register renaming, but the architectural state of a hardware thread still only includes the 16 GP registers (or 8, in 32bit mode), 16 or 8 vector registers, etc. etc.